# How to get Pinch Zoom working on webview_flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I am trying to get Pinch Zoom working in the webview_flutter addon/plugin. 
It is a simple test app, I am referring to this tutorial as a guide https://blog.geekyants.com/webviews-in-flutter-87194714ce3d.

I added this gesturerecognizer code in.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: WebView(
              key: _key,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              initialUrl: _url,
              gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory < VerticalDragGestureRecognizer > (
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()))..add(Factory < ScaleGestureRecognizer > (
                () => ScaleGestureRecognizer())), ))
        ],
      ));
  }
```

But it does not enable any pinch zoom functionalities.

I am testing with 2 different Android devices, one is running Android OS 8.0, another is running Android OS 7.0. 
I am using the Flutter latest Beta.

Appreciate any help or tips to getting this feature working.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pinch to zoom is enabled by default on iOS,

follow this pull request and modify `FlutterWebView.java` to enable it on android:

[link here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2451)

Comment: Are you sure about the iOS zoom? I just tried it on an iOS device and pinch zoom does not work.

Comment: @kakyo can you give more context? physical ios device or simulator? which plugin - webview_flutter or flutter_webview_plugin? which website pages are tested? etc.

Comment: I was on an iPhone6s, running iOS 13, with `webview_flutter`. It's a local html file in the assets folder of my app.

Comment: @kakyo my guess is your local html doesn't support pinch to zoom

Comment: I just tested with the latest github copy of webview_flutter's example, trying to open a website instead, still no pinch on iOS. Zooming works fine on my html files with a quick Electron test app.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Plugins > webview_flutter-2.0.2 >
/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebView.java

I only got this working changing this file, adding this code:

```
// Allow zoom.
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// Hide buttons.
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

*The same thing as 'Wenhui Luo' did.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flutter_inappwebview plugin instead. And pinch to zoom in and out works by default with this plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

```
 InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.webUrl)),
        onLoadStart: (controller,uri){
        },
        onLoadStop : (controller,uri){
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [`flutter_webview_plugin`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) like this:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter WebView Demo',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  routes: {
    '/': (_) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter WebView Demo'),
    '/widget': (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
      url: selectedUrl,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget webview'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,   // zoom
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Waiting.....'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  },
);
```